# Groovy equivalent of Java's String.format

Tags: groovy

The below Java code gives errors in Groovy..

```
  private String getSignature() {
    String timestamp = getUTCTimestamp();
    String nonce = getNonce();
    String digest = getPasswordDigest(nonce, timestamp);

    return String.format(
            "UsernameToken Username=\\"%s\\", PasswordDigest=\\"%s\\", Nonce=\\"%s\\", Created=\\"%s\\"", apiUsername, digest, nonce, timestamp);
}
```

Specifically the String.format line, how to re-write in Groovy?

Comment: This code should work fine with Groovy just as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do

```
private String getSignature() {
    String timestamp = getUTCTimestamp();
    String nonce = getNonce();
    String digest = getPasswordDigest(nonce, timestamp);

    "UsernameToken Username=\"$apiUsername\", PasswordDigest=\"$digest\", Nonce=\"$nonce\", Created=\"$timestamp\""
}
```

Comment: If you use double, double quotes, you won't need to escape them in the string!

Answer (score 1):

You can use GroovyStrings in preference to String.format or string concatenation; GroovyStrings let you interpolate variables into the body of the string, as described in [the documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation):

> Any Groovy expression can be interpolated in all string literals, apart from single and triple single quoted strings. Interpolation is the act of replacing a placeholder in the string with its value upon evaluation of the string. The placeholder expressions are surrounded by ${} or prefixed with $ for dotted expressions. The expression value inside the placeholder is evaluated to its string representation when the GString is passed to a method taking a String as argument by calling toString() on that expression.

There are multiple ways to delimit string literals, you can avoid having to escape the double-quotes by picking a different delimiting syntax, such as [dollar-slashy](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_dollar_slashy_string), [slashy](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string), or [triple-double-quoted](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string).

Btw in Groovy you don't need the semicolons, and you need to use return explicitly only if you're returning early from the method:

```
String getSignature() {
    String timestamp = getUTCTimestamp()
    String nonce = getNonce()
    String digest = getPasswordDigest(nonce, timestamp)

    $/UsernameToken Username="${apiUsername}", PasswordDigest="${digest}", Nonce="${nonce}", Created="${timestamp}"/$
}
```